# Question about a continuous periodic function

Tags: functions, continuity, periodic-functions

Consider the continuous and periodic function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with period $T > 0$ so that $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for any $x$.

**Question:** Prove that there exists a $c$ such that $f(c)=f(c+ \pi)$.

**Note:** This is not claiming that the period of $f$ is $\pi$, and is not a restatement of the definition of periodic. Many comments below reflect this incorrect interpretation of the statement of the problem.

Comment: what is pi suppose to be?

Comment: Pi is the irrational number 3.1415926....

Comment: what thought have you put into the question?

Comment: I was thinking that there always exists a line of symmetry. Intermediate value theorem might turn out to be useful. But can't use it properly

Comment: Is the question complete?  What if the function has a period larger than $\pi$?

Comment: Yes, i got it from a trustworthy source

Comment: Are you serious ? By the definition of periodicity, the equality is true for any $c$, regardless continuity.

Comment: Someone edited my question.. I posted the original one again

Comment: I edited your question. The time period is either $\pi$ or T. Also you state periodicity again in symbolic form.

Comment: I think this question, although lacking the OP's efforts to solve it is a valid question. Many users (myself included) were evidently confused as the question asked looks very much like a potentially incorrect restatement of the definition of periodic. The question was edited erroneously by another user to reflect that interpretation. It would have been helpful to seek clarification from the OP before making such an edit. The solution provided by Coolwater is a correct argument.

Comment: Note that the intuitive interpretation of this question is that: If you shift the graph of a continuous periodic function (by $\pi$ here, but that isn't relevant), the shifted graph will intersect with the unshifted graph. This doesn't necessarily hold if the function is allowed to to be unbounded or discontinuous.

Comment: Question is clear now, +1 and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Periodicity and continuity of $f$ implies boundedness, hence $f$ has a maximum and a minimum within the closure of a period $P=[0, T]$. Say the minimum and maximum are attained at $t_1\in P$ and $t_2\in P$. We have then

$$f(t_1) - f(t_1 + \pi) \leq 0 \quad f(t_2) - f(t_2 + \pi) \geq 0$$

as well as continuity of $f(t) - f(t + \pi)$.

Comment: I think this is right

Comment: This is correct. Thanks for the clean argument, Coolwater! I knew your answer was solid, but had no choice but to work up a few examples to convince myself since the question looked like an incorrect restatement of the definition of periodic. Apparently many other users were confused as well! Note that the use of $\pi$ here is irrelevant, thus we can generalize: For any continuous periodic function $f$, and $\forall a$, $\exists c$ such that $f(c)=f(c+a)$.